# opengl + Qtwidget don't work

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm creat a opengl program in qt application, and I'm using this video tutorial for this   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18.
But my widget don't work, it does show image, only the image that was behind the screen. this and an example (from is my opengl view):

http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/screenshot_from_2014-07-09_02_44_19-png

And this is my codes:

my Qtwidget view:

```
#include "telafotos.h"
#include "ui_telafotos.h"

TelaFotos::TelaFotos(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TelaFotos)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

TelaFotos::~TelaFotos()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

My QGLWidget:

```
    #include "imagemfestivalgl.h"

ImagemFestivalGl::ImagemFestivalGl(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
}


void ImagemFestivalGl::initializeGL(){
    glClearColor(1,1,0,1);
}

void ImagemFestivalGl::paintGL(){

}

void ImagemFestivalGl::resizeGL(int w, int h){

}
```

Comment: Is that really all to initialize a working openGL session with that widget? I've never used it but it looks short to me...

Comment: have a look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-hellogl.html there seems to be more to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the viewport in resizeGL

```
void ImagemFestivalGl::resizeGL(int w, int h){
    glViewport (0,0,w,h);
}
```

and clear the draw buffers in paintGL

```
void ImagemFestivalGl::paintGL(){
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

This should result in a blank area